# Multiple Jenkins jobs on multiple platofrms

Tags: matrix, jenkins

I am trying to build multiple Jenkins jobs, e.g. job1, job2 where jobs2 is downstream job1, each one needs to run on multiple platforms, e.g. Win, Mac, Unix

I need job2 on Mac to start once job1 on Mac has finished, same for others... but cannot find a simple way to do this simple thing!

I tried the Matrix configuration, parametrized trigger, extended trigger, NodeLabel, but non did the right job

This task looks simple but I could not achieve! Any help is really appreciated

Comment: Can you describe a bit of why some of the solutions you tried didn't work?

Comment: Matrix configuration did the job, but job2 will only get triggered after all job1 platforms are finished, this could be ok, but I have about 10 jobs, 6 platforms each, this could take a lot of time

Comment: It would complete in the time of the slowest platform, because it builds all the platforms in parallel (unless you deliberately set it to serial.)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the [Build Pipeline Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Build+Pipeline+Plugin) or [Pipeline Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Pipeline+Plugin) to help address this? You can also consider creating these pipeline dynamically depending on job dependency and then run.

Seems like a fit to me.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/13134432)

Comment: Understood and agreed.